# How to import multiple files in R?

Tags: r

I wrote the following code to read the existing files from the given link, but in the end the files variable returns the file empty. Can you help me?

```
# List of files in directory
files = list.files(path="https://github.com/buds-lab/building-data-genome-project-2/tree/master/data/meters/raw", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
files
```

Comment: `list.files` only looks at local filesystems, it does not support network protocols. Perhaps you should look to scraping (with `rvest`) or API-retrieval (with `httr`).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are interested in accessing files from the GitHub repo you can make use of the `git2r` and clone the repo to temporary directory for the purpose of accessing files.

```
library("fs")
library("git2r")
temp_import_dir <- path_temp("githubRepo")
repo_url <- "https://github.com/buds-lab/building-data-genome-project-2"
clone(url = repo_url, local_path = temp_import_dir)
# Getting the actual files
files_list <- dir_ls(path = path(temp_import_dir, "data", "meters", "raw"),
                     glob = "*.csv")
```

## Second scenario

`read_csv` also facilitates reading directly from a remote connection so you can pass directly file urls to the function. In the example below I'm already binding them in one data frame

```
file_paths <- c("https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/buds-lab/building-data-genome-project-2/master/data/meters/raw/chilledwater.csv",
                "https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/buds-lab/building-data-genome-project-2/master/data/meters/raw/electricity.csv")

data_files <- map_df(file_paths, read_csv)
```

---

## Remarks

- If you are working with a GitHub repo, cloning the repo appears to be a best option, as:

  - This is a common operation that is well maintained and supported, example `git2r`
  - You can leverage all of the usual git functionalities, such as branching and historical commit analysis. That may make sense if you wish to interact with the files
  - Cloning via `git2r` is fast due to compression
  - If your analysis develops you may wish to consider including this repo as a sub-module in your own repo to facilitate future maintenance and reproducibility